# Intellij IDEA, when open new task - it doesn't create local branch from origin

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-branch

IDEA version - 2017.2.

If create task from Jira (for which branch have been already created in *remote*)

[image]

and select this branch for this Jira from dialog
[image]

it wont create local branch on my computer and just point to commit instead
[image]

Of course if try to commit you will not succeed without local branch.[image]

So it would be very handy to say IDEA to create local branch automatically. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea currently does not allow checking out remote branches without creating a local one that tracks it. Here is the request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140077

Since there is no local branch that matches the remote one, you need to use the `Create branch` and select the remote one in the From dropdown.

Comment: Will wait for change :) Thanks

Comment: The referenced request has been rejected in favor of [Unified checkout action for remote branches](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208517), which has been implemented since 2019.3. But while opening a new task and specifying a remote branch, it still (tested in 2023.3) does not create a local branch. I think a new request is needed

Comment: There actually is a feature request for this, but it has status "Shelved" meaning it's not planned to be implemented.. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164646